# Regex Python Grouping with '.*'

Tags: regex, expression, nsregularexpression, qregularexpression

I have a regular expression that involves some grouping, and I am having a difficult time understanding why the last character is being grouped alone using this regex:

Regex: `([A-Za-z]+).*([A-Za-z]+)`
String Example: `Hello World`

I dont get why the 'd' is grouped alone by itself, I know it has something to do with `.*` but cannot wrap my head around this when testing on https://www.regex101.com

If I put the `.*` in the front of the expression only the l and the d are captured, why is that?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: The `.*` is being greedy and grabbing all the characters from space to `d`. Make it non-greedy (lazy) with a `?` i.e. `([A-Za-z]+).*?([A-Za-z]+)`

Comment: but why stop at d? how come it does not stop at l or r?

Comment: Because it grabs as many characters as it can *without* preventing the regex from matching.

Comment: that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: it would not match with the z though right ?

Comment: Lucy, I misspoke in my earlier comment.  For the string `abczefgzhijzk`, the regular expression `[a-z]*z` matches `abczefgzhijz`. The regular expression `[a-z]*?z` (or `[a-y]*z`) matches `abcz`.  If you want to match up to the first `z` (`abc`), use `[a-y]*` (or `[^z]*`). If you want to match up to the last `z` (`"abczefgzhij"`), use `[a-z]*(?=z)`, `(?=z)` being a *positive lookahead*.